# Xcode4 Core Data Model Editor Display Problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, xcode4

I've had this problem ever since upgrading to xcode 4.  In the core data model editor, I can't see my diagram view.   Everything else seems to work, but mostly the graphic view is just blank.  If I click around on entities in the list, I get a screen that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hzo0.jpg

Comment: I haven't hit this problem but the X4 data model editor is definitely busted.

Comment: I'm with TechZen, in Xcode 4.0.x the model editor is not really useable. Better to stick with 3.2.6 until there's a new Xcode 4 release where this is fixed.

Comment: I've had strange behaviour too in Xcode 4 when importing and using a model created in Xcode 3.x, especially with the designer not showing relationships. Watching the WWDC 11 videos, I saw there will be a dropdown in The next Xcode version to select the CD model's Xcode version...

Comment: Well, thanks everyone for the comments - at least I know that I'm not alone.   I love the large graphic view plotted out to give to our server side guys, but I guess I'm going to have to find another way until Apple fixes this.

Comment: I've just seen this too. Everything worked fine in the past (in Xcode4) apart from occasional crashes around the model editor. Then, within all a project, I seem to be getting this too. All projects were created in Xcode4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit this problem, here is how I fixed it:

1. Quit Xcode
2. In a terminal or finder, remove the file myapp/myapp.xcdatamodeld/myapp.xcdatamodel/layout
3. Restart Xcode and open your project

Note: No guarantees you won't lose any work product.  This solution allowed me to return to a working graphical state at the point just before the graphical problem began and I didn't lose any work.

Comment: Can't find the file you mention. Where is it ?

Comment: In newer versions of Xcode, there may not be a `layout` file.  Instead you'll only have `myapp/myapp.xcdatamodeld/myapp.xcdatamodel/contents`.  If you open this file in a text editor, you'll see it's just a bunch of XML.  At the end of it is a section that describes where entities are positioned in the editor view.  Delete this section, save the file, and the reopen your data model in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar to Chris:

1. quit xcode
2. in finder, locate your datamodel file
3. copy the file to a safe place (I used my desktop)
4. delete the file from your project folder
5. open your project in xcode
6. right click in the navigator and "Add files"
7. select the datamodel in the safe place from step 3
8. tell it to copy the files if necessary
9. click "Add"

Answer (score 2):

Check your 'inverse' relationships. A mismatch in these can make the 'Graph' view go blank.

For example, if entities A and B have a relationship, ensure relationship 'ab' has the proper inverse 'ba' and vice-versa. The Xcode UI will enable you to manually enter non-matching inverses and then it's only a matter of time before you see the blank graph.

Answer (score 1):

I`m using Xcode 4.2.1 and I have found the same problem. I had to open the file "contents" on vi and edit the positions at the end of the file. Maybe because some bug, there was big negative values. Once the file was edited, everything was put into place again.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4.2.1, the file you need to edit is the "contents" one people have mentioned in other answers. I also noticed really strange negative values in my contents file, but changing to positive values didn't fix anything, and then clamping them to smaller values didn't help either.

Eventually I quit Xcode, backed up my model file, and then just deleted all the entries in the  section at the end of the contents file. I then launched XCode and added and deleted an Entity. It worked for a minute, but reverted to the strange state after I moved a few entities around.

What finally fixed it for me was deleting an Entity I had just created before the problems started. It was a child of another entity, and I think I had created a loop of some sort that was confusing the parser. I had a different entity altogether with relationships to both the parent and child entities. Deleting the child entity finally fixed things right up and I just had to lay out the existing entities again in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with Xcode 4,3,2, the issue is even if I fix the location of entities on the graphical view of the model, if I switch to edit a text file and then go back to the model, it has already lost the location of many, but not all entities.

What helped, is to make sure to manually save the file before I edit anything else. Otherwise the changes were not persisted. Unnerving that apple's tooling can be so unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.5, deleting the myapp/myapp.xcdatamodeld/myapp.xcdatamodel/contents file did not fix anything--rather, it made my data model completely unusable.

Instead, I changed all the wild negative values in the contents to 0. Then they showed up again in the model editor, and I manually repositioned them. However, positioning them in certain arrangements would cause the model editor to freeze, so I would just undo the last change and arrange them differently.

Here's to hoping Apple debugs the editor in 4.6. Best to file a bug report

Answer (score 0):

For xcode 4.5.2 (4G2008a), I simply went over all my relationships, as noted by Jaysen Marais, and ensured they were all correct with matching/appropriate reverse entities.

That made the graph display again.

Also typically this will happen when you are adding new entities or changing them, so ensure to look at those.