# Core data "Diagram tools" not showing on the window

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am using Xcode 4.2, in the core data editor the  "Diagram tools" are not showing on the window. How do I see them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode4 Core Data Model Editor Display Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433549/xcode4-core-data-model-editor-display-problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the entity relationship type view where each entity is a box, and the relationships are lines between them, this is toggled in the "editor style" at the bottom of the screen.

See figure 1-10 [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Orientation/Orientation.html) - the editor style is the segmented control at the bottom right:

[image]

Comment: yes jrturton you got the problem . but in my editor view its not coming. how do i make them visible

Comment: What can you see at the moment? A list type view of each entity?

Comment: I want to see the design view click on editor style 2nd tab... .then there is no controls of "zoom ,Line "..are coming with the horizontal scroll bar.